# Having Async/Await Promise troubles - Javascript/Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I am really getting a headache trying to make use of the async/await functionality when using for loops. I am using Node.js version: v8.6.0

In short, I am trying to retrieve many rows from a database and then push them all to an array and return that array.

I have successfully done this using callbacks but can't figure out how to do it with async/await.

**My current code using callbacks that works**

```
function main(db) {
    gatherDates(db, function(dates) {
        console.log(dates); //successful
    });
}

function gatherDates(db, callback) {
    const dates = [];
    let today = getToday();

    dates.push(today);

    let dateQuery = "SELECT date FROM event_dates";

    db.query(dateQuery, (err, newDates) => {
        for(let row of newDates) {
            dates.push(row.date);
        }
        callback(dates);            
    });
}
```

**The code that fails trying to use async/await**

```
async function main(db) {
    let dates = await gatherDates(db);
    console.log(dates); //undefined or not all of the data
}

function gatherDates(db) {
    const dates = [];
    let today = getToday();

    dates.push(today);

    let dateQuery = "SELECT date FROM event_dates";

    db.query(dateQuery, (err, newDates) => {
        for(let row of newDates) {
            dates.push(row.date);
        }
        return Promise.resolve(dates);
    });
}
```

I have googled trying to find a solution, I have tried using multiple promise and then calling `return Promise.all(promises);` at the end but it did not work. I have tried `return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>resolve(dates))};`. I have looked at Promise and async/await tutorials and examples which usually work for me but when it comes to looping through data that is where I am having an issue. I know there is something fundamental that I am missing so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to `return` the promise from inside the `db.query` callback, [which can't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572) (and even when you tried to use the promise constructor, you did it inside there, with the same effect as `Promise.resolve()`). The [proper way to promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) is to use `new Promise` outside, so that you can `return` it from your outer function, and only put the `resolve` inside the asynchronous callback.

```
function query(sql) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
        db.query(sql, (err, res) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(res);
        });
    });
}

async function gatherDates(db) {
    const dates = [getToday()];
    const newDates = await query("SELECT date FROM event_dates");
    for (let row of newDates) {
        dates.push(row.date);
    }
    return dates;
}
```

Comment: worked great! and now I understand promises a lot better. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly returning a `Promise` object from your asynchronous function, here is the solution:

```
function gatherDates(db) {
    const dates = [];
    let today = getToday();
    dates.push(today);
    let dateQuery = "SELECT date FROM event_dates";

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        db.query(dateQuery, (err, newDates) => {
            for(let row of newDates) {
                dates.push(row.date);
            }
            resolve(dates);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You should absolutely do that, but that is not what he is requesting, I prefer to answer with the exact required behavior.

Comment: I don't see where in his question the OP is requiring to use bad practices.

Comment: Bad practices ? Sure.